# Can I use three additional screens with my laptop?

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T480 with an Intel i7-8550U and three additional screens on my table. Right now I am only using two of these.

Intel states that # of Displays Supported for this cpu is 3.
And I wonder now, will it be possible to connect my laptop with a dockingstation to all three screens? or does the laptops screens also count? Could I use all three screens when I turn of the laptops screen? and will this then be done automatically?

The three screens are two Benq, 24", 1920x1080 and one Dell, 27", 3840x2160.

[CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i7-8550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html)

[dockingstation](https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/lenovo-thinkpad-usb-c-dock-60w-2-gen-hdmi-displayport-60w-usb-typ-c-usb-typ-a-dockingstation-10829677?isSale=true&supplier=406802)

Comment: I believe that laptop has (internal + 2 external displays) 3 displays maximum.  You might be able to do one more using a USB video adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laptop screen counts as a display, however, you can close the laptop lid if you want to use the 3 external monitors.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. The output connector may not support 3 screen output.

Answer (score 0):

As docking stations usually can only connect to 2 monitors directly at the same time, the 3rd monitor should have a DisplayPort output for [daisy chain / MST](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln293813/how-to-daisy-chain-multiple-monitors-using-displayport-multi-stream-transport-mst?lang=en).
You can also buy a USB adapter with DisplayLink chip from [Cable Matters](https://www.cablematters.com/search.aspx?PageSize=20&PageNum=1&SearchTerm=displaylink) - i use one to connect my PC to a 4K TV.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I close my laptop and turn off its screen, how @Chaim proposed.

**Using the usb-c docking station for all screens**
When I connect all screens via the docking station they all work and get a signal. Downside is that the 4k monitor only has a resolution of 1920x1080 and the two full-HD monitors have 800x600.

**Using the usb-c docking station for two screens and another usb-c to hdmi adapter for the 4k screen**
When I connect the two full-HD monitors via the docking station and the 4k monitor via a seperate usb-c to hdmi adapter all screens work in their full resolution.